# How to add CtStatement using inria spoon

Tags: java, inria-spoon

I have a requirement where I need to remove JNDI lookup code from class and @Autowire the same.

**Current class:**

```
public class BankProcessor {
    public Collection getAccountInformation(String customerId){
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    ArrayList accountBeanList = new ArrayList();
        CustomerHomeLocal customerHome = (CustomerHomeLocal)context.lookup(CustomerHomeLocal.JNDI_NAME);
        CustomerLocal customer = customerHome.findByPrimaryKey(customerId);
        Iterator accountIterator = customer.getAccounts().iterator();               
        }
}
```

**Expected class**

```
public class BankProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerHomeLocal customerHome;

    public Collection getAccountInformation(String customerId){
        ArrayList accountBeanList = new ArrayList();
        CustomerLocal customer = customerHome.findByPrimaryKey(customerId);
        Iterator accountIterator = customer.getAccounts().iterator();           
        }
}
```

I have tried creating codeSnippet from `classfactory.Code().createCodeSnippetStatement("CustomerHomeLocal customerHome;")` but not able to add it to `CtType`.

Also, I can't use `createField()` method as I want to autowire user defined classes and adding user-defined jar,importing classes in my code will be a tidious job.

Any pointer on this would be appreaciated. Thanks!